# Cordova Android Facebook Connect Plugin - Init & Login Error, Weird Results

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have just upgraded to the latest version of the Phonegap Facebook Plugin for Android, as the earlier version's FB.ui feed dialog callback returns OK on both cancel and successful sharing, and my app critically depended on differentiating these actions.

However, upon upgrading to the new plugin and running it, there appears to be a few big problems:

- The plugin returns "fail on init" when starting, but it is still half-working: When I try to run FB.login, the response object no longer returns an "authResponse" sub-object with accessToken, expiry etc. Instead, the response object returns a profile similar to /me query result, with properties like id, work, email, username and such. If I additionally try to run FB.api("/me"), it fails with "no active access token" error.
- I've tried compiling with the FacebookLib included in the source, or separately Facebook's SDK 3.8, but it results in the same problem.
- The FB.Event.subscribe is working, and
- FB.ui also works when I manually call it with feed dialog, and cancel/share callback works fine

I monitored logcat in Eclipse, and I don't see any Class Not Found errors when running the app, except for some error messages which I'm not sure if they are related:

> 04-15 21:06:43.546: W/BroadcastQueue(2238): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.net.conn.INET_CONDITION_ACTION flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION due to registered receiver BroadcastFilter{42328c98 u0 ReceiverList{428c0658 17124 com.facebook.katana:dash/10088/u0 remote:428c0590}}
>
> 04-15 21:06:43.546: W/BroadcastQueue(2238): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION due to registered receiver BroadcastFilter{42328c98 u0 ReceiverList{428c0658 17124 com.facebook.katana:dash/10088/u0 remote:428c0590}}
>
> 04-15 21:06:43.551: W/BroadcastQueue(2238): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION due to registered receiver BroadcastFilter{43351748 u0 ReceiverList{433516c8 17124 com.facebook.katana:dash/10088/u0 remote:433513d8}}
>
> 04-15 21:06:46.056: W/fb4a(:):ImmutableBundle(16369): Unsupported value type in bundle for key fb4a_new with value {"new_version":"154780","min_version":"148914","new_version_url":"https://m.facebook.com/mobile_builds?build_number=154780&no_fw=1","new_version_notes":"","everstore_handle":"FuuCCQA5cQwCBxEkAFAANnxuPwYAAAA:"}
>
> 04-15 21:06:46.056: W/fb4a(:):ImmutableBundle(16369): Unsupported value type in bundle for key fb4a_master_new with value {"new_version":130613,"new_version_url":"https://m.facebook.com/mobile_builds?build_number=130613&no_fw=1"}

To summarize, Facebook Connect for login no longer works with weird return results, but a standalone FB.ui feed dialog call works.

Can someone please advise? If I revert to older version of this plugin, the login works, but sharing callback doesn't... so it is a real dilemma.

Comment: I have the same issue.
It looks like something is blocking the internet connection.

I think this is a system wide problem, because I have some other apps to, wich cannot connect at the same time.

According the Locat outputs, it looks like something remove you permission to access "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"

Did you already try to reboot you device ? This helped sometimes for me.